# Quickly navigating to a date in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

How can I quickly navigate to a given date, say, a past date about 2 years ago, in Google Calendar?

Currently have have to click on the previous month button about 20 times.
I have tried entering dates / months / years in the search box without effect. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply press `g` which will bring up a "Go to date" dialog.

This is native and doesn't rely on Google Labs or G Suite. Maybe this was part of the Google Labs beta and was merged into the main product, or maybe it was there all along.

Press `?` to pop up a list of other helpful keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 3):

In Google Calendar labs you can enable the **Jump to date** feature. It will allow you to jump to any date in seconds.

Comment: As somebody else pointed out, Google Labs is no longer available in the free calendar.

However, you can press `g`  for the "Go to date" dialog, which is super handy.

Answer (score 1):

Another option... Type in the URL bar of your browser:
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/month/YYYY/MM/DD
where YYYY/MM/DD is the date you want to jump to.

For example:
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/month/2015/10/16

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Google Labs is no longer available to non-G Suite users. To jump to a specific remote date, you can do the following:

1. Create an event on that day you want to jump to
2. Delete that event after you are directed to that day.